# Python - quick interpolate by left value

Tags: python, performance, numpy

This is a task. 
I have some points:
(All as numpy arrays)

```
xp = [1001, 1010, 1020, 1025]
yp = [0, 0, 1, 1] # two values, if this helps
```

And I wanna interpolate this for the numpy array [1000, 1001, ... 1049, 1050].
So, that each value is equal to the LEFT side of interval:

```
1000 - (some, doesn't matter)
1001 - 0
1002 - 0 (because left - in 1001 is 0)
1003 - 0 
....
1009 - 0
1010 - 0
1011 - 0
...
1019 - 0
1020 - 1
1021 - 1
...
1024 - 1
1025 - 1
1026 - 1
...
1049 - 1
1050 - 1.
```

I don't want to do this in pure Python, because this is slowly.
I can use numpy and scipy. Can I solve quickly this without Cython or С++?

Comment: Show us what you have done already before saying that Python is slow for this. It seems to be list construction, which is quite well handled by Python :)

Comment: That is not interesting. Python loops is always more slowly than native code, working in numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify endpoint expicetly:

```
>>> x = np.array(xp+[1051])
```

get lengths:

```
>>> np.diff(x)
array([ 9, 10,  5, 26])
```

and repeat:

```
>>> np.repeat(yp, np.diff(x))
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Or to get as 2-d array:

```
>>> np.vstack([np.arange(x[0], x[-1]), np.repeat(yp, np.diff(x))]).T
array([[1001,    0],
       [1002,    0],
       [1003,    0],
         ...
       [1020,    1],
         ...
       [1050,    1]])
```